# Hammer.js Carousel Start Pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, hammer.js

Heyho,

I´am working on a project in my university and I´d like to use "Hammer.js".
I´ve downloaded the Carousel-Example and it works perfectly for me.

But I would like to start a the middle pane of my code and it´s not so simple I think.

It´s something like this:

http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/6326/schemeas.jpg

so Hammer.js starts always with the green screen. But I like to start with the yellow one.
I´ve added one swipe right to the init function but it looks horrible when the page is loading and could not be the goal ^^

I hope anyone of you have an idea how to solve my problem.

Comment: You will need to provide a demo example of your problem.

Comment: @NULL they did didn't they? They downloaded the carousel example off the hammer.js homepage.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling

```
carousel.showPane(1);
```

That will display the second pane instantly. You will want to put this near the bottom, right after where it says.

```
carousel.init();
```

If you're feeling adventurous you could try and make it automatically start with that pane as there's a variable inside the Carousel function called current_pane which is set to a default of 0 (the first pane). Altering this may work too but might require more code somewhere else. Experiment!

**edit**

NULL is right, it does animate it. Here's a more in depth method to set it without animation:

I found that the method responsible for changing which pane is showing was the setContainerOffset mthod which could be passed a variable to animate it. I previously told you to use showPane(2) but that then called

```
setContainerOffset(offset, true)
```

which caused the animation occur. What you should do instead is make a slightly different version of showPane...

```
this.setPane = function( index ) {
         // between the bounds
        index = Math.max(0, Math.min(index, pane_count-1));
        current_pane = index;

        var offset = -((100/pane_count)*current_pane);
        setContainerOffset(offset, false);
    };
```

You'll find it's almost identical to showPane except for the name and the fact that it calls setContainerOffset with animation: false. This will immediately show the pane of your choice and can be called using

```
carousel.setPane(index);
```

What I've done is added this to the init function so that it looks like this:

```
 this.init = function() {
        setPaneDimensions();
        var c = this;
        $(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function() {
            setPaneDimensions();
            c.setPane(current_pane);
            //updateOffset();
        })
    };
```

Now you can change

```
var current_pane = 0;
```

to whatever you want and the carousel will always start with that pane when it's initialised! simple!

Comment: This add's the `animate` class to the container. Think that will cause the slide to animate.

Comment: @user2377170 great! Could you accept it as the answer then please?